# getting only time timestamp from string

Tags: php, datetime, php-carbon

Suppose I have a time string '9:30' which I want to convert to timestamp.
What I do right now is extracting it and manually calculate the timestamp.

```
list($hour, $minute) = explode(':', '9:30');
$timestamp = $hour * 3600 + $minute * 60;
```

I'm wondering whether there is a smart way using Carbon or DateTime object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to get a timestamp from only hour or minute, as timestamp is number of seconds from 00:00:00 Thursday 1 January 1970 (check [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) for more details). So without the date part you can't have a timestamp. Could you please explain how you're planning to use this?

If you're planning to calculate a different timestamp from a given datetime, then you can just do it differently. Say you're planning to get the timestamp 1 day or 24 hours after given time, then you can do it like this (non object oriented way):

```
$givenTimestamp = strtotime('17-06-2018 09:30:00');
$dayInSeconds = 24*60*60;
$calculatedTimeStamp = $givenTimestamp + $dayInSeconds;
```

If you're just trying to get how many seconds has been passed for the time section of the timestamp (like 9:30 in your example for a given day), then you can just do it like this:

```
list($hour, $minute) = explode(':', date ('H:i', strtotime('2018-06-16 09:30:00')));
$secondsSinceStartOfDay = intval($hour)*60*60 + intval($minute) * 60;
```

You may get the same result without using the intval on $hour and $minute, but it would be better to use intval on them to avoid possible issues in some cases.

### Update with Carbon

From Carbon documentation, it seems like you still need the date part to generate the timestamp. So if you have your $date like this '2018-06-16' and $time like this '09:30', then you can recreate your datetime like this:

```
$dateTimeString = $date .' '. $time .':00';
$carbonDateTime = Carbon::parse($dateTimeString);
// $carbonDateTime will now have your date time reference
// you can now get the timestamp like this
echo $carbonDateTime->timestamp;
```

Comment: I separate date and time fields therefore I have two inputs with date and time. I am able to convert date to Carbon but not able to convert time to carbon. I will probably go back to use strtotime()

Comment: In that case, why don't use both date and time to rebuild your timestamp? I didn't use Carbon before, but I just have checked the documentation, and updating my answer for that.

Comment: So I guess there is no way to get timestamp from only time value but I will accept your answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can, as @kamil-ciekalski mentioned, but the timestamp you'll get would be relative from today's date. so if you're using strtotime('9:30'), then it would be timestamp of todays 9:30. Same with when using Carbon.

Answer (score 1):

use `strtotime()`
[manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$time = '9:30';
$timestamp = strtotime($time);
echo date('H:i',$timestamp);
```

Comment: good idea! Thanks. I like this solution but would like to see whether there are other solutions using Carbon.